# visual studio enforce build error using code analysis

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, spell-checking

I'm new to C# and the project as well. My team members are making a lot of spelling mistakes in strings. My manager want that the build should fail if there are spelling errors. While searching I found out **Visual Studio Code Analysis tool** and **Spell Checker Plugins**.

I have configured Code Analysis tool so that it shows analysis error if there are spelling mistakes.  Is there any way to a enforce it as a build failure in such situation? And is it a good approach? Is there any better approach? I'm using VS2012.

**EDIT**

I have configured Code Analysis to run on every build. Now it's showing an error on running project after saving the code but if I run the code again (without saving), it runs successfully. But I want it show show error on every run until Code Analysis errors are resolved.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good approach. If you have problems with correct spelling in strings you should put the strings into a database or an external file. There you can check and change the spelling without any need to touch the source-code again.

Comment: @user1567896 thanks for your suggestion. But the project is in a _very_ mature state so I don't think this is a feasible solution. What we want is to correct the spellings errors in the existing code. I have asked my manager to consider the approach that you have suggested for future code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think enforcing build error using code analysis is a good approach, it is really disturbing for the developer while writing the code and the developer can just turn off or uninstall the plugin in their environment.

What you might need to have is setting up a build server that runs the code analysis as part of it. It could be [cruise control .net](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) or [team city](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity) or [sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/).

You can run other things on that server, like unit test, auto deployment, complexity report, commenting, etc.

Comment: Will they be able to find spelling and/or grammatical errors in the strings?

Comment: It depends on the plugin you will use on the build server, if you manage to find grammatically error using code analysis, all you need to do is configuring it on the build server. You might want to check out about stylecop and fxcop.